# Flutter Android native code not saving changes unless I restart Android studio

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, dart

I am facing a weird problem in android studio while using flutter. I am working on a complicated flutter project which requires some native code, so, am writing some platform code using flutter platform channel(writing for android), whenever I make changes to the code in the android platform and run the app, the code changes does not reflect on the app unless I restart Android studio. What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the app as native doesnt support hot reload like flutter

Comment: I uninstalled and installed but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

go to  File->invalidate Caches/Restart,
then click on open for editing in Android Studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).